# Is there any way to turn off just notifications on installing McAffee from Dell?

Tags: windows-11, notifications, dell-xps

I bought a computer from Dell which included McFee. However I do not want that product, so I uninstalled both their LiveSafe and WebSafe (?) applications.

When turning on the computer a day later I get a notification from Dell about installing it again, with seemingly no way to turn off just that notification for more than a day (see screenshot).

Screenshot of the snooze box:

[image]

I know I can turn off all notifications from Dell, but I would prefer not too. Is there any other way to avoid getting notifications about installing McAfee every day?

Comment: That isn't a prompt to reinstall the software, that is an offer on a subscription, what you received from Dell was a trial for McAfee. I would just uninstall the Dell software responsible for the offer, if you are not interested, in the offers Dell is offering.

Comment: You might also look at tools to remove trial-ware and other undesired apps: https://alternativeto.net/software/pc-decrapifier/ . BTW, be sure Windows Defender or other AV is working!

Answer (score 0):

Dell article
[How to Uninstall Dell Digital Delivery](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000200562/how-to-uninstall-dell-digital-delivery)
has this method :

- In the Windows Task Manager find and stop
  "Dell Digital Delivery Service"
- Run *Settings > Apps & Features*
- Click on each of the following apps and for each click *Uninstall*:

  - Dell Digital Delivery Services
  - Dell Digital Delivery.

Comment: It would be nice to have an explanation for the downvote.

Comment: I agree, your answer is correct

Comment: I mean this will turn off notifications on installing McAffee, but it will also remove all other notifications, which is directly counter to what is asked for? Maybe I am misunderstanding part of the answer @Moab, harrymc?

Comment: @eirikdaude: It's all-or-nothing.

Comment: I know that, I am merely positing that this isn't an answer to the question as it's currently worded. I guess if it was formulated a bit differently it could be a frame challenge though...

Comment: @eirikdaude: As happens in many posts on our site, we can only suggest what is possible, no more.

Comment: Which is why I am saying it could be rephrased as a frame challenge, if you did mention that what's asked in the question is not possible in the Dell update manager. However, you do not which is why I offered up as a guess as to why you had received a downvote.

Comment: @eirikdaude: Sorry to have misunderstood, but this was part of a series of downvotes and the reason wasn't technical.